# How to remove notice inside search.php when no results are found?

Tags: search, page-template

I have created search.php from Twenty Eleven theme search template. Search template works fine but i am having a problem when **no results are found**.

I am getting this PHP Notice:  ***Notice: Trying to get property of non-object wp-includes/post-template.php on line 29***

Post-template line 29 looks like this:

```
function get_the_ID() {
return get_post()->ID;<-this is the source of the problem 
}
```

I am assuming that this happens because `get_post()->ID` is not set (when no results are displayed) because inside my search template i have put this code:

```
<?php if ( !isset ($post->ID)) {
echo 'not set';<- this will echo "not set" if NO results are found and 
               PHP notice will be displayed:(               
}
else{
echo 'set';<- this will echo "set" if results ARE found and 
               PHP notice will NOT be displayed  
}
?>
```

So my question is how to SET `$post->ID` (if it is not set) in order to remove PHP Notice?

Any help is massively appreciated Thank You!!

Search php code:

```
<?php

 get_header(); ?>
 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
 <?php get_sidebar('secondary'); ?>
 <?php if ( !isset ($post->ID )) {
  echo 'not set';
   }
   else{
   echo 'set';
   }
   ?>
<div id="blogwrapper">
<div id="blog">
<h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s' ,'your-override' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class();?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>


   <div class="entry">  
                <div class="featured_img">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();
      echo '<div class="featured_caption">' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt . '</div>';?>
     </div><!--/featured_img-->
        <?php  // let's enable more link on pages...
        global $more;
        $more = 0;
        ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?> 
            <div class="clear"></div>               
            <div class="custom_fields"><?php the_meta(); ?></div><br/>
            <p class="postmetadata">

            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br/><?php the_tags('Tags:', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
            <?php _e('Posted on:&nbsp;'); ?><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y'); ?><br/>               
            <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments &#187;', '1 Comment &#187;', '% Comments &#187;'); ?> <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' &#124; ', ''); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <div class="navigation">
    <?php
    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
     ?>
    </div>
<?php else : ?>
        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found'); ?></h1>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.'); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </article><!-- #post-0 -->      
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        </div><!--/blogwrapper-->   
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_post() returns the post object to the loop. So when you look for its ->ID if no object is there you try to make php to look for ID of nothing, and it gives you the notice. Change post->ID for

```
    if( ! get_post() )
```

Comment: Up voted and accepted thx @Svetlana Silina!

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like that my problem wasn't search.php but my footer.php this code caused an error `<?php post_comments_feed_link( $link_text = 'Comments RSS', $post_id = 'post_id', $feed = 'rss2' ); ?>` anyway my footer code looked like this :

```
<div id="footer">
 <?php wp_footer(); ?> 
<p>
<strong>Copyright 2013 <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | All Rights Reserved.</strong>
Designed by Dex
</p>
<p><a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>">Latest Stories RSS</a> | 
<?php post_comments_feed_link( $link_text = 'Comments RSS', $post_id = 'post_id', $feed = 'rss2' ); ?></p>  
</div>
</div><!--/wrapper-->
```

And I have modified it using @Svetlana Silina answer to this:

```
<div id="footer">
<?php wp_footer(); ?> 
<p>
<strong>Copyright 2013 <?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | All Rights Reserved.</strong>
Designed by Dex
</p>
<p><a href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>">Latest Stories RSS</a> |    
<?php if(get_post()){
?>
<?php post_comments_feed_link( $link_text = 'Comments RSS', $post_id = 'post_id', $feed = 'rss2' ); ?></p>      
<?php } else if(!get_post()){ 
?>
<?php post_comments_feed_link( $link_text = 'Comments RSS', $post_id = '1', $feed = 'rss2' ); ?></p>    
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

And all is good now no PHP notice even if no results are shown.
Life is good again:=)